# Observable with an a decision tree

Tags: swift, reactjs, rx-java, rx-swift

I need a function that encapsulates a complicated IAP purchase tree into a simple attemptPurchase function that returns a boolean observable (true -> success, false -> cancelled, error -> any error)

But I am stumped at how to create that function, mainly because the start of the decision is async.

Decision tree and code below.

[image]

```
// fails -> missing return function
// but I cannot return the credit check, since the execution is different depending on the result

func attemptPurchase(amount: Int) -> Observable<Bool>{
  
  let creditCheck = creditCheck(amount)
   
  creditCheck.filter{$0}.subscribeNext{ _ in
    return Observable.just(true)
  }

  creditCheck.filter{$0}.subscribeNext{ _ in
    return confirmIAP().processIAP()
  }
}

func creditCheck(amount: Int) -> Observable<Bool>{
  return API.creditCheck.map{$0 > amount}
}

func confirmIAP() -> Observable<Bool> {
  // UI for confirming IAP
}

func processIAP() -> Observable<Bool> {
  // UI for uploading IAP on my server
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it:

```
func attemptPurchase(amount: Int) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return creditCheck(amount)
        .flatMapLatest { (enoughCredit: Bool) -> Observable<Bool> in
            if enoughCredit {
                return Observable.just(true)
            } else {
                return confirmIAP()
                    .flatMapLatest { (isConfirmed: Bool) -> Observable<Bool> in
                        if isConfirmed {
                            return processIAP()
                        } else {
                            return Observable.just(false)
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, much appreciated! There is another answer i found more rx-ty. just added it. what do you think?

Comment: They behave differently, but I'm not sure which one you're needing.

Comment: why are they different? both achieve the aim of the question

Comment: For example, in my code, if `enoughCredit` is `true`, then the final `Observable` only emits `true`, and that's all it does.  However, in yours, if `enough` is `true`, then it will *also* run `processIAP()`.  So the flows are different.  Also, `flatMap` vs `flatMapLatest`, which means that if you're in the middle of processing an event while another event comes through, `flatMap` will let them both happen, while `flatMapLatest` will cancel/dispose the first one.

Answer (score 0):

From [iankeen](https://github.com/IanKeen)'s answer in the RxSwift slack group:

```
func attemptPurchase(amount: Int) -> Observable<Bool>{
    return creditCheck(amount)
        .flatMap { enough in
            return (enough ? .just(true) : confirmIAP())
        }
        .flatMap { ready in
            guard ready else { /* failure */ }
            return processIAP()
        }
}
```